# Measure non-randomness of numeric license plates

Tags: algorithms, entropy, maximum-entropy

License plates for cars in Switzerland have the 2-letter abbreviation from the 
Canton and then between 1 and 6 numeric digits.

[image: commuter car]

There are no alphabet characters in the license plate, and therefore no way to purchase vanity plates, like in the States.

[image]

When you register a car, you recieve a randomly selected plate number which is normally a larger number (in Zürich, it's going to be 6 digits and more likely to be 900k instead of 100k).

But [there is an auction](https://www.auktion.stva.zh.ch/) where you can buy number plates, and the demand (final auction price) of these number plates is based on at least these factors, I think in this order:

1. how low is the number (1000 > 10000 > 100000)
2. how repeating is the number (55555 > 29370)
3. how symmetric is the number (567765 > 768483)

**My question: What would be a useful algorithm to score the non-randomness (low entropy) of integers with varying length?**

I've looked at [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) - here is a sample Python function ([source](https://lorenzoriano.wordpress.com/2010/07/09/quantifying-the-wow-effect-of-a-robot-part-i/)):

```
def kolmogorov(s):
    l = float(len(s))
    compr = zlib.compress(s)
    c = float(len(compr))
    return c/l
```

but I think I would need an algorithm specifically for integers - so that the sorted `1234` scores higher than the non-sorted `9362`.

Another algorithm is to [measure entropy of an integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24753601/2327328), but maximizing entropy seems to be a different goal. (Or can I resort to minimize entropy and then count how many steps between my start and end?)

Comment: As you intimate, the sense of "non-randomness" is *psychological*.  I would suggest it is *purely* psychological.  Repetitions, forms of symmetry, etc., are categories imposed on perceptions by the human mind: they are not properties inherent in the number sequences.  How, then, could we hope to solve this problem without obtaining relevant data?

Comment: The final auction price (or number of bids) could be the metric for psychological perception of something like non-randomness. But I guess I'm looking for something like the [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) with integers

Comment: Using the Kolmogorov complexity of an integer string seems like the most natural to me. From your source "the Kolmogorov complexity of an object, such as a piece of text, is the length of the shortest computer program (in a predetermined programming language) that produces the object as output." Since the length of the actual object, degree of repetition and symmetry all contribute to a shorter computer program, this captures a wide range of inherent structure in the license plate number that is perceived by humans. (...)

Comment: (...) One potential miss would be significance of specific digits: i.e. if certain digits were the current year or the birth year of the driver; an aversion to the number 13, etc.

Answer (score 3):

All combinations of integers, absent a human 'lens' on them, are equally random.  This is like the lottery: you are just as likely to win with the 6 digits 1,2,3,4,5,6 as with any other combination.

In fact, lottery 'bidding' is not random.  People tend to focus, for example, on date representations (usually birthdays or anniversaries), so numbers above 31 seldom get played.  And, since months end at 12, the numbers 1-12 get overplayed.

You can see that in the lottery numbers people choose.  But, as someone else noted, this is just human superstition at work.  The metric would be based on the auction data, not on some entropic study of digits per se.